# Как убрать или изменить поле имя и фамилия в плагине Лейка для Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Есть плагин Лейка для пожертвований. Оттуда в форме оплаты нужно убрать поле имя или же заменить на номер тлф. Как это сделать? Использование required= "false" , не дало результатов. может что - то еще нужно?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Почему такое не спросить на форуме поддержки плагина? https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/leyka/

Comment: SeVlad там он до сих пор на модерации..Где обычно размешается условие об обязательном заполнении поля в плагинах? Не знаете?